# Indent or beautify scss in Visual Studio Code Mac

Tags: css, macos, sass, visual-studio-code, indentation

indentation or beautify files (sass and css) in VSCode drives me nuts. I installed the "Beautify css/sass/scss/less" extension.

After that i've two commands: Format document (option-shift-F) or Format Selection (cmd-K cmd-F). When selecting a a few lines with the mouse and use "Format Selection", it's formatting the whole file. Tried it with sass and css files.

I'm doing something wrong? What do i have to do when i wanna indent or beautify only selected lines?

Answer (score 0):

I work with JavaScript in visual studio code and it working

Shift + Alt + F will work

Answer (score 0):

Try with the [scss-formatter extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sibiraj-s.vscode-scss-formatter). For scss woks greatly.